STM32 LoRaWAN - debug failure to join network
We have an STM32-based board running an application which someone else wrote a couple of years ago. The code was written using STM32CubeWL v1.1.0, which includes LoRaWAN v2.3.0 code.
We have tried to update the code to use STM32CubeWL v1.3.0, and the code compiles -- but it fails to join the LoRaWAN network.
Any suggestions what to look for that could be affecting the ability to join the LoRaWAN network / gateway?
